# how to get array from object with index as one of the object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter, reducers

I have an object

```
const items = {
  "123": {
    "key": 123,
    "name": "one name",
    },
    "456": {
    "key": 456,
    "name": "two name",
    },
    "789": {
    "key": 789,
    "name": "three name",
    },
    };
```

Need to filter this from below array, with array index as object.key

```
const myFilter = [123,789];
```

Code I am trying is as below but it returning array inedx as 0,1,2... but I need the index to be object.key.

```
let selectedItems = myFilter.map((key) => {
        return items[key];
      });
```

Current output :

```
[0:{
  key: 123,
  name: "one name"
}, 1: {
  key: 789,
  name: "three name"
}]
```

Expected Output

```
[123:{
  key: 123,
  name: "one name"
}, 789: {
  key: 789,
  name: "three name"
}]
```

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kb374exh/2/

Comment: Your Expected output is not valid array, or even a object for that matter.

Comment: yup, and also your `items` variable is an object of object not array of object. so, you can't use array method for that

Comment: Also, why ````123```` and ````789```` and no the ````456````?

Comment: @ikiK - I tried to edit the output format. Basically I need an array index to be the key property of the object and not 0,1,2...., sorry If Its confusing

Answer (score 0):

Your actual output is actually correct and the only possible result from mapping the `myFilter` array to the matching properties from `items`.

```js
const items = {
  "123": {
    "key": 123,
    "name": "one name",
  },
  "456": {
    "key": 456,
    "name": "two name",
  },
  "789": {
    "key": 789,
    "name": "three name",
  },
};

const myFilter = [123, 789];

const selectedItems = myFilter.map((key) => items[key]);

console.log(selectedItems);
```

The logged output you see is including the array index. You likely are seeing the index included when logging in the browser.

[image]

If you want an array of objects where the original key is the new index then the best you can likely do is an array of length <highest key> and a bunch of "holes" that are simply undefined.

[image]

```js
const items = {
  "123": {
    "key": 123,
    "name": "one name",
  },
  "456": {
    "key": 456,
    "name": "two name",
  },
  "789": {
    "key": 789,
    "name": "three name",
  },
};

const myFilter = [123, 789];

const selectedItems = Object.entries(items).reduce((selectedItems, [key, value]) => {
  if (myFilter.includes(value.key)) selectedItems[key] = value;
  return selectedItems;
}, []);

console.log(selectedItems);
```

If you are ok with the result being an object then you can have more succinct output, you'll basically end up with back with an object with key-value pairs filtered out.

[image]

```js
const items = {
  "123": {
    "key": 123,
    "name": "one name",
  },
  "456": {
    "key": 456,
    "name": "two name",
  },
  "789": {
    "key": 789,
    "name": "three name",
  },
};

const myFilter = [123, 789];

const selectedItems = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(items).filter(([, value]) => myFilter.includes(value.key)));

console.log(selectedItems);
```